# How do I change default color for first part of dropdown navbar in bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, colors, navbar, dropdown

I am looking to change the initial items color in bootstrap navbar drop-down. I got most of the parts of it fixed but sadly cannot figure out the initial part.

[what it looks like before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gzk6.png)

this is what I want the navbar to look like.

[what it looks like when I click dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGJh0.png)

this is what it looks like afterwords despite a lot of css manipulation so far. anyone know what I need to do to change that specific part?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here? Can you explain more about what the problem is and what you'd like it to look like?

Comment: Ok, with the dropdown Games once clicked it turns white. How do I keep it at the current color or at least just a slightly darker color?